# update database based on user enter from array

Tags: php, mysql

**Data entered by user:**

```
"product_description": [{
    "language_id": 1,
    "name": "okayt321sd1a"
}
```

**Update database:**

```
foreach ($data['product_description'] as $product_description) {
    foreach ($product_description as $key => $value) {
        $a[$key] = $value;

        if($a[$key]){
            $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape(html_entity_decode($product_description['name'])) . "', meta_keyword = '" . $this->db->escape(html_entity_decode($product_description['meta_keyword'])) . "', meta_description = '" . $this->db->escape(html_entity_decode($product_description['meta_description'])) . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($product_description['description']) . "', tag = '" . $this->db->escape($product_description['tag']) . "',
                                  page_title = '" . $this->db->escape($product_description['page_title']) . "',
                                  highlight = '" . $this->db->escape($product_description['highlight']) . "',
                                  whatbox = '" . $this->db->escape($product_description['whatbox']) . "' WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', 
                              ");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I update data based on user enter, for example, if user enter

```
"language_id": 1,
"name": "okayt321sd1a"
```

then I only update this 2 data to database other data will remain, if enter 3 data:

```
"language_id": 1,
"name": "okayt321sd1a"
page_title
```

then I only update this 3 data to database other data will remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do a function that will build the sql for you. I am assuming you are using PDO *(I don't know, but this example uses PDO)*. You should bind parameters/values either way. To add in custom fields, just use `array_merge()`. You can use `array_diff()` or `unset()` to remove unwanted values/keys:

```
function updateProductDesc($array,$where,$db)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            $sKey           =   ":{$key}";
            $bind[$sKey]    =   htmlspecialchars($value);
            $sql[]          =   "`{$key}` = {$sKey}";
        }

        $bind[":where"] =   (int) $where;
        $query  =   $db->prepare("UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."product_description SET ".implode(", ",$sql)." WHERE `product_id` = :where");
        $query->execute($bind);
    }

foreach ($data['product_description'] as $product_description) {
    foreach ($product_description as $key => $value) {
        $a[$key] = $value;
        if($a[$key]){
            updateProductDesc($product_description,$product_id,$this->db);
        }
    }
}
```